# vb.net save in Word 2010

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop, save-as

**Platform:** Windows and Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express

**The problem:** I have a Word template made in Word 2007. When the application is 
run in a machine with Word 2010, the SaveAs-command doesn't work. It works fine
to open a template and add data and even a photo to bookmarks in the template.

Here is the statement that doesn't work(`vPath` contains path and filename.):

```
oDoc.SaveAs(vPath.ToString)
```

I have tried different solution but nothing works:

```
oDoc.SaveAs(vPath.ToString, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument)
oDoc.SaveAs(vPath.ToString, 17)  ' WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF
oDoc.SaveAs(vPath.ToString, 6)   ' WdSaveFormat.wdFormatRTF
```

**References:**

- Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library

**Import statements:**

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using Office 14 and downloaded a 2007 template.  The following code works for me.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
....
Dim objApp As Word.Application
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
objApp = New Word.Application()
objDoc = objApp.Documents.Open("c:\delme\templateoriginal.dotx")
objDoc.Activate()
objApp.Selection.TypeText("some text")
objDoc.SaveAs("c:\delme\template.dotx")
objDoc.Close()
objApp.Quit()
objDoc = Nothing
objApp = Nothing
```

Did you check that your vPath is correct?  I am not sure what vPath is, but ToString is a method right so are you missing parenthesis by chance?

```
vPath.ToString -> vPath.ToSring()
```